# Drawing a line on the right margin

Tags: tables, exam

I need to prepare an exam paper in LaTeX and I have to draw two lines all across the right margin of the sheet with written at the beginning of the page "DO NOT WRITE IN THIS MARGIN". Is there a way to write in the right margin? Or should I use a long table? I am sorry if I don't post any minimal example, but I have utterly no idea of how to start!

An example of the lines is the following:

[image]

the vertical lines are meant to continue all along the sheet, and continue (with the same label at the beginning) in the following page.

Cheers

Comment: Could you attach a sketch of what the expected result should look like?

Comment: I have edited the question with a sketch of what I want to do. I hope that's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is MWV, you can improve it

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\geometry{left = 2cm, right = 1cm, marginparwidth = 2cm, includemp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, black]
  \coordinate (mNE) at (current page marginpar area.east |- current page header area.north);
  \coordinate (mNW) at (current page text area.west |- current page header area.north);

  \coordinate (mSE) at (current page marginpar area.east |- current page footer area.south);
  \coordinate (mSW) at (current page text area.west |- current page footer area.south);

  \begin{scope}[line width = 3pt]
    \draw[] (mNE) ++(0, -1cm) -- (mNE) -- ++(-1cm, 0);
    \draw[] (mNW) ++(0, -1cm) -- (mNW) -- ++(1cm, 0);
    \draw[] (mSE) ++(0, 1cm) -- (mSE) -- ++(-1cm, 0);
    \draw[] (mSW) ++(0, 1cm) -- (mSW) -- ++(1cm, 0);
  \end{scope}

  \draw (current page marginpar area.north east) -- (current page marginpar area.south east);
  \draw (current page marginpar area.north west) -- (current page marginpar area.south west);

  \node[left] at (current page marginpar area.north west) {MARKS};
  \node[right, text width = 2cm] at (current page marginpar area.north west) {DO NOT \\ WRITE IN\\ THIS \\ MARGIN};

\end{tikzpicture}

{\bf FORMULAE LIST} \par

The roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are $\displaystyle{x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

> **EDIT**

To include this on every page use the `everypage` package

```
\AddEverypageHook{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, black]
    \coordinate (mNE) at (current page marginpar area.east |- current page header area.north);
    \coordinate (mNW) at (current page text area.west |- current page header area.north);       
    \coordinate (mSE) at (current page marginpar area.east |- current page footer area.south);
    \coordinate (mSW) at (current page text area.west |- current page footer area.south);       
    \begin{scope}[line width = 3pt]
      \draw[] (mNE) ++(0, -1cm) -- (mNE) -- ++(-1cm, 0);
      \draw[] (mNW) ++(0, -1cm) -- (mNW) -- ++(1cm, 0);
      \draw[] (mSE) ++(0, 1cm) -- (mSE) -- ++(-1cm, 0);
      \draw[] (mSW) ++(0, 1cm) -- (mSW) -- ++(1cm, 0);
    \end{scope}       
    \draw (current page marginpar area.north east) -- (current page marginpar area.south east);
    \draw (current page marginpar area.north west) -- (current page marginpar area.south west);       
    \node[left] at (current page marginpar area.north west) {MARKS};
    \node[right, text width = 2cm] at (current page marginpar area.north west) {DO NOT \\ WRITE IN\\ THIS \\ MARGIN};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it looks very elegant. However, I need the line to be present in every page (or, at least in every page but the first and the following marking guidance), and that's a bit of a problem. Do you think it is possible to fix that?

Comment: @Logos Absolutely, I added an update to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the writing on every page, you could use `eso-pic`:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage[left=.5in, right=2in, marginparwidth=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

% for testing purpose only:
\usepackage{mwe}
%\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
        \AtPageLowerLeft{% 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            % angles
            \coordinate (pagene) at (.98\paperwidth,.98\paperheight);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (pagene) -- +(-1,0) -- (pagene) -- +(0,-1);
            \coordinate (pagenw) at (.02\paperwidth,.98\paperheight);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (pagenw) -- +(1,0) -- (pagenw) -- +(0,-1);
            \coordinate (pagese) at (.98\paperwidth,.02\paperheight);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (pagese) -- +(-1,0) -- (pagese) -- +(0,1);
            \coordinate (pagesw) at (.02\paperwidth,.02\paperheight);
            \draw[line width=4pt] (pagesw) -- +(1,0) -- (pagesw) -- +(0,1);
            \end{tikzpicture}}
        \ifthenelse{\value{page}>2}{% if page > 2 add:
        \AtPageLowerLeft{% 
            \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
            % Writing at the very top
            \node[anchor=north east, align=center,
            font=\small] (W) 
            at (.95\paperwidth,.95\paperheight) 
            {DO NOT \\ WRITE IN\\ THIS \\ MARGIN};
            \node[anchor=north east, 
            font=\bfseries, align=right] 
            at (W.north west) {MARKS};
            % vertical lines
            \draw[thin] (W.north west) -- +(0,-.9\paperheight);
            \draw[thin] (W.north east) -- +(0,-.9\paperheight);
            % horizontal line
            \draw[thin] (W.south west) -- (W.south east);
            \end{tikzpicture}}%
        }{}%
        }

    % your content here 
    \textbf{FORMULAE LIST}

    The roots of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ are $\displaystyle{x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}}$

    % this is for testing purpose only:
    \blindtext[30]
\end{document}
```

Page 1 only corners:

[image]

Page 2 only corners:

[image]

From page 3 on, corners, lines and writing:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it looks awesome. Is it possible to have also the right line on it? And what about the corners? Is that the possibility of adding them as well?

Comment: I am sorry for bothering again, but the solution does not fit my needs because the angles must be in every page, while the line for marking should be only after the first page with the students data. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: I mean both! In the first page I need only the corners, then there is another page without the vertical lines (and "MARKS" and "DO NOT WRITE ON THIS MARGIN") and then the test begins with the margin line.

Comment: That's gorgeous! I didn't know the package `ifthen`. It is absolutely terrific! Thank you very much and apologies for all the troubles I have caused with this.

Comment: No problem! `ifthen` is really useful, even though the experts use the TeX `\if...\fi` directly :):):)

Comment: I am not that much expert, and I think I will use very often this package. It has made my day!

Comment: @Logos The same for me! I've done a little correction for the angle (the output does not change).